# Apache spark - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, jar, apache-spark

I have maven based mixed scala/java application that can submit spar jobs. My application jar "myapp.jar" has some nested jars inside lib folder. one of which is "common.jar". I have defined class-path attribute in Manifest file like `Class-Path: lib/common.jar`. Spark executor throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:com/myapp/common/myclass` error when submitting application in yarn-client mode. Class(com/myapp/common/myclass.class) and jar(common.jar) is there and nested inside my main myapp.jar. Fat jar is created using spring-boot-maven plugin which nest other jars inside lib folder of parent jar. I prefer not to create shaded flat jar as that would create other issues. Anyway spark executor jvm can load nested jars here?

**EDIT** spark (jvm classloader) can find all the classes those are flat inside myapp.jar itself. i.e. com/myapp/abc.class, com/myapp/xyz.class etc.

**EDIT2** spark executor classloader can also find some classes from nested jar but it throws NoClassDefFoundError some other classes in same nested jar!
here's the error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, host4.local): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/myapp/common/myclass
    at com.myapp.UserProfileRDD$.parse(UserProfileRDDInit.scala:111)
    at com.myapp.UserProfileRDDInit$$anonfun$generateUserProfileRDD$1.apply(UserProfileRDDInit.scala:87)
    at com.myapp.UserProfileRDDInit$$anonfun$generateUserProfileRDD$1.applyUserProfileRDDInit.scala:87)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:249)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:172)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.myapp.common.myclass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 14 more
```

I do submit myapp.jar with `sparkConf.setJar(String[] {"myapp.jar"})` and also tried setting it on `spark.yarn.executor.extraClassPath`

**EDIT 3**
As a workaround, I extracted myapp.jar and set `sparkConf.setJar(String[] {"myapp.jar","lib/common.jar"})` manually and error went away but obviously I have to do that for all the nested jar which is not desirable.

Comment: whoever downvoted it please care to justify

Answer (score -2):

You can use --jars options, to give comma separated list of jars while starting the Spark Application.

Something like

```
spark-submit --jars lib/abc.jar,lib/xyz.jar --class <CLASSNAME> myapp.jar
```